# How to data bind dialog in Caliburn.Micro using x:Name

Tags: material-design, caliburn.micro

I have a C# program that launches a dialog inside a DialogHost:

```
Dialogs.ViewModels.WriteProgramToDatabaseDialogViewModel vm = new Dialogs.ViewModels.WriteProgramToDatabaseDialogViewModel();
var view = new Views.WriteProgramToDatabaseDialogView
{
      DataContext = vm
};
var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog");
```

DialogHost is a feature of ButchersBoy's MaterialDesign framework.  [DialogHost](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs)

The WriteProgramToDatabaseDialogViewModel is simply a class that derives from Caliburn Micro's "Screen".

Now, Caliburn Micro has spoiled me and I am used to being able to declare controls and use the x:Name property in the XAML to bind them.  This does not work at all in the dialog's ViewModel and I am failing to understand why.

Fortunately, I can still setup databinding for controls by explicitly setting it:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding MyTextProp}"/>
```

In order to bind buttons to methods in the ViewModel, I can explicitly bind the Click event:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action RunMethodInVM]"/>
```

My question is: can with anyone with experience of both Caliburn Micro and Butchers Boy's Materialize explain why the x:Name abstraction doesn't work inside a DialogHost?

Comment: I have the same Problem with the `DrawerHost.RightDrawerContent` now. x:Name binding for a buttons doesnt work in `DrawerHost.RightDrawerContent`. Thanks for pointing out that the Event binding still works